# Accessing a array of Structs using pointer notation

Tags: c++

I am trying to learn C++ on my own and was trying out this. I have a struct one of whose member is an array of another structs. I have a question about alternative notation.

The structs that I have defined are

```
struct employeeRecordT {
    string name;
    string title;
    string ssnum;
    double salary;
    int withholding;
};

struct payrollT {
    int num;
    employeeRecordT *array;
} payroll;
```

I am allotting memory to payroll using the following construct

```
payroll.array = new employeeRecordT[payroll.num];
```

where payroll.num is indicating the number of elements in the array. I can access the element name of the employeeRecordT by using the array notation e.g.

```
payroll.array[i].title
```

I wanted to know how to access this using the pointer notation, I have tried

```
payroll.(array+i)->name = "Vikas";
```

and I get the following error message from g++

toy.cc:30:13: error: expected unqualified-id before '(' token
toy.cc:30:14: error: 'array' was not declared in this scope

I am trying to understand what I should be using and why? Could you guys help explain.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Vikas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(payroll.array+i)->name = "Vikas";
```

`array` is a member of `payroll`, so when you were doing `payroll.(array+i)`, the bracket notation (i.e. "do this first") was trying to use a variable `array`, and not the one within the scope of `payroll`.

Of course, using C++, the better solution is Neils. Use a std::vector instead of your own dynamically allocated storage if possible.

Comment: Tried what you were recommending and it works. I should have thought of that. In hindsight, it appears obvious. I agree with both Neil and you that I should be using vector (and in general use STL wherever possible). I was doing this just for learning.

Answer (score 5):

If it hurts, don't do it. Use a std::vector of your structures instead.

Comment: -1: When people bring up a really broken question which shows that they've jumped into the implementation before thinking about the design, it's all fine and well to give high-level advice. But to be fair, this was a precise and specific question with a simple direct answer, no need to sandbag the guy for asking.